# Python Selenium - Server Authentication Issue

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm having a problem with authentication, such that my request:

- Fails when web driver is active in Firefox (Selenium opened the browser).
- Works when web driver is not active (request sent via PostMan, FF14, etc.)

Request:

```
GET /ecmuw/ECMWeb/uw/login HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept-Language: en-us, en;q=0.5
```

The exact same code and drivers used to work w/ the follow setup:

- 32Bit OS
- 32Bit Python 2.7
- Selenium 2.37.0
- Firefox 14

I have recently moved to a 64Bit system, which may be the source of the problem. All components (Python, Selenium, FF14) are still 32Bit, only the OS has changed.

**NOTES:**

- I cannot change FF to a later version.
- The most recent Selenium has never worked with FF14. I used the following matrix to identify a Selenium 2.37.0 that had full capabilities, which previously worked: 
  https://github.com/santiycr/selenium-firefox-support-matrix

Comment: Why gecko driver, if your FF is < version 48 than GeckoDriver is not required. Is there any dependencies due to which you can not update the FF or selenium?

Comment: Thanks for that. I was under the impression the driver was required. The users the code is being developed for are stuck with FF 14. I was using the attached matrix to determine the appropriate selenium. The newest has never been able to properly control FF14.